# What Java KeyEvent can a num pad generate?

Tags: java, keyevent

In a swing program I am trying to receive input specifically from the num pad keys on the keyboard using key bindings.

```
myPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8, 0), “numpad8”);
myPanel.getActionMap().put(“numpad8”, numPad8);
```

Works fine if I got the num lock on, which is as expected, however if I add:

```
myPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP, 0), “numpad8”);
```

Without num lock on, my keyboard does not cause numPad8 Action to be called (in fact it seems to generate KeyEvent.VK_UP instead). This is surprising to me as the documentation of KeyEvent specifies that KeyEvent.VK_UP is

> Constant for the non-numpad up arrow key.

and KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP

> Constant for the numeric keypad up arrow key.

So my question is: If I want my code to support as many keyboard set ups as possible what KeyEvents should I expect from the num pad? Should I add KeyEvent.VK_8 to the above just be safe, for example?